# In React, is it okay to use getElementById, querySelector, etc versus useRef if you don't perform any DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Specifically used just to view the heights/widths (getBoundingClientRect) of elements. I recently encountered a need to find all the separate heights of a dynamic amount of child elements to perform a calculation. I added a ref within the child component, and passed a function down from the parent in an attempt to update the parent's list of child dimensions (which was in state). I found this to be overtly complex and confusing and unreliable. So, in the parent, I just did a simple for loop with getElementById after giving each child an id of `child-${index}`.

I know you are NOT supposed to do any direct DOM manipulation in React; however, if your goal is read some data only, then is it an issue or bad practice?

Comment: Might be OK if you really can't refactor a ref to look decent

Comment: Nothing wrong with it IMO, as long as you don't mutate the DOM directly.

Comment: The fact that "there is a DOM" is mostly irrelevant for React code to do its thing, that's actually just an implementation detail (which is why react-native exists. Same idea, no DOM anywhere to be found). So if you can use refs: definitely use refs, and if you can get the job done with props passing, also definitely do that. You really only want to use browser APIs if you need to work with not-managed-by-React content, from within React.

Answer (score 4):

It might not be a problem right now, but I would consider using `getElementById` instead of a `ref` bad practice in general (or at least call it "a workaround").

#### 1

`getElementById` works "outside" of React, so you are not using React here.

That might work for now, but also might interfere with what might do React at some time.
E.g. you might access or hold a reference to a DOM node, and React might decide to remove that node while you were reading it. I don't see why this might happen in your
example, but when using two separate systems it is hard to keep track of the possible consequences.

#### 2

With the id `child-${index}` you have introduced a logical dependency (coupling) between the parent and the child.
The id `child-${index}` acts as a reference here, and has to be kept in sync manually.

This might be easier in a short term, but is actually more complex as a general approach (e.g. less maintainable, reusable, ...).
You could say, Reacts whole purpose is to avoid such complexities.

Your components should be as independent of each other as possible, and should only communicate through the props.

#### suggestion

I suggest to avoid both `getElementById` *and* passing a `ref`, and have the children know their size (e.g. using a custom hook),
and pass only the sizes up to the parent (not the ref).

If that is not possible, I would prefer to use `refs`.

Also note that "confusion" is not the same as "complexity": Confusion can be decreased by acquiring more information, but complexity is an
inherent property of a system.